# What class is the starship with angled nacelles in the Second Battle of Chin'toka?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, spaceship, object-identification

What is the Federation starship class that immediately comes into view with angled warp nacelles in the following clip?

Just to be clear, this is the ship that is being asked about:

[image]

Comment: I believe this is referring to the ship seen at the 0:07 mark in the video, near the middle of the frame. I originally thought it referred to the Defiant itself, as the nacelles look angled when viewed from above.

Comment: The link takes you immediately to 0:07

Comment: Weird. For some reason it started at the beginning for me. What I get for viewing at work, I suppose.

Comment: mmmm. weird. yes you are correct it is that vessel.

Comment: I love the way Sisko says "fire" (x2) in this clip. It is as though he is totally p*ssed off with the dragging on of the Dominion war now, and,... AND the Breen have enough audacity to enter into the conflict at this stage! But, the consequences (spoiler) are dramatic!

Comment: I added a still showing the ship in question, because I was a little confused.  If I got the wrong ship, feel free to delete it and please accept my apologies.

Comment: Yep that's the ship

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I realised it was this (helped by the link provided in another question):

https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Steamrunner_class

The strut geometry matches.

[image]

Comment: Yup - the rear nacelles glowing blue are the giveaway. The Akira / Saber only have impulse in the aft - which are red

Comment: This class of ship is also in `Star Trek: First Contact` during the battle with the Borg cube

Comment: It looks way more cool from behind than from above. If only it was more like the usual saucer+engineering design but with those angled nacelles.